# Sharing a user table between Rails and Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, postgresql

I have inherited a rails app as part of a project that requires a separate app to be built with the only commonality being the users table in PostgreSQL (the rails app is using devise for auth). I am inexperienced in Rails and would like to build the separate app in Django. Is is feasible to have the Django app use its built in auth user model on top of the user table from the Rails app?

Thanks.